# How to get duplicate values from Json array and push in another json array in node.js

Tags: json, node.js

I have one json array. From that I want to push duplicate invoice number records into another json array in node.js.
I have json array as:

```
jarray:[{
"invoice": "C1"
"name": "Amit"
},
{"invoice": "C1"
"name": "Anish"
},
{
"code": "C2"
"name": "Anuj"
},
{
"code": "C3"
"name": "Sumit"
}
]
```

new json array I want as :

```
jarray1:[{
 "invoice": "C1"
    "name": "Amit"
    },
    {"invoice": "C1"
    "name": "Anish"
    }]
```

How can I do this in node.js?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using either `underscore` or `lodash`, both of which can be fetched (by those names) using `npm install` and both of which will work with the following code:

```
var _ = require('lodash');

var original = [
    {
        "invoice": "C1",
        "name": "Amit"
    },
    {
        "invoice": "C1",
        "name": "Anish"
    },
    {
        "invoice": "C2",
        "name": "Anuj"
    },
    {
        "invoice": "C3",
        "name": "Sumit"
    }
];

var grouped = _.countBy(original, function (item) {
    return item.invoice
});

var duplicateInvoiceIds = [];
_.filter(grouped, function (qty, key) {
    if (qty > 1) duplicateInvoiceIds.push(key);
});

var result = _.filter(original, function (item) {
    return _.indexOf(duplicateInvoiceIds, item.invoice) > -1;
});

console.log(result);
```

This is a 3-step process (for clarity). Note that I've assumed the original data should have said "invoice" throughout and not switched to "code" partway through. If not, put "code" back in and those will just be silently skipped.

1. Group by invoice (`{ C1: 2, C2: 1, C3: 1 }`).
2. Find the keys with a value over 1, as these are invoice IDs with multiple entries (`[ 'C1' ]`).
3. Return (and show) the original items but filtered to where their IDs are in the collection from the last step.

This results in:

```
[ { invoice: 'C1', name: 'Amit' },
  { invoice: 'C1', name: 'Anish' } ]
```